Instrument builder in a scientific lab w/ academic funding using a technique described in a patent for research, and for developing new technology
From this answer to Is it allowed to use patents for new inventions?:

From https://www.uspto.gov/patents/basics/essentials#questions,  "A U.S. patent gives you, the inventor, the right to 'exclude others from making, using, offering for sale, or selling' ...."

situation 1
If a home-made scientific instrument in an academic institution used for research and funded by public funding agencies for academic research turns out to include some technique or design that is at least arguably covered by a patent, and the instrument results in a publication and further academic funding, it looks like that's covered by "making" and "using" even if there's no potential for "selling".
I'm not asking if such a lawsuit is likely, only if this is considered infringing on the patent.
situation 2
What if, down the road, a different, new, and patentable design is spun off as the basis for a company, and it does not include that technology, but the technology was physically used, temporarily in-house during research necessary to develop a new invention, then disassembled/discarded?
i.e. "You used my idea to develop your idea, you gotta pay me."

This seems to be related to https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Research_exemption#:~:text=The%20common%20law%20research%20exemption,Cutter%2C%2029%20Fed.

@NateEldredge that looks like the basis of an answer, yes. I don't think what's described would be considered to be for "amusement, to satisfy idle curiosity, or for strictly philosophical inquiry."

Added the [tag:united-states] tag since that seems to be the jurisdiction that interests you, but if not then please edit.

Structurally, I seem to recall that a patent is a right to exclude someone from using the invention and that the patent holder has to ask you to not use it for you to infringe, but I may very well have the wrong. "You used my idea to develop your idea, you gotta pay me." Even if you are infringing, the precise remedy may not be all profits from your improvement invention, it might be the fair market value profit lost from not paying for one unit for a licensed holder of the patent, e.g.

Situation #2 would have a devastating affect on innovation if it were true.

@NateEldredge thanks,for the purposes of this question, it's a good place to start.

A controlling decision in infringement by academic use is MADEY v. DUKE UNIVERSITY (CAFC 2002) 307 F.3d 1351.
Dr. John M.J. Madey was an inventor of US Patent Nos. 4641103 and 5130994.

In 1989 Madey moved his free electron laser ("FEL") research lab from Stanford to Duke. The FEL lab contained substantial equipment, requiring Duke to build an addition to its physics building to house the lab. In addition, during his time at Stanford, Madey had obtained sole ownership of two patents practiced by some of the equipment in the FEL lab.


At Duke, Madey served for almost a decade as director of the FEL lab. During that time the lab continued to achieve success in both research funding and scientific breakthroughs. However, a dispute arose between Madey and Duke. Duke contends that, despite his scientific prowess, Madey ineffectively managed the lab. Madey contends that Duke sought to use the lab's equipment for research areas outside the allocated scope of certain government funding, and that when he objected, Duke sought to remove him as lab director.  Duke eventually did remove Madey as director of the lab in 1997. ... As a result of the removal, Madey resigned from Duke in 1998. Duke, however, continued to operate some of the equipment in the lab. Madey then sued Duke for patent infringement of his two patents, and brought a variety of other claims.

The Federal Circuit held:

regardless of whether a particular institution or entity is engaged in an endeavor for commercial gain, so long as the act is in furtherance of the alleged infringer's legitimate business and is not solely for amusement, to satisfy idle curiosity, or for strictly philosophical inquiry, the act does not qualify for the very narrow and strictly limited experimental use defense. Moreover, the profit or non-profit status of the user is not determinative.

The Supreme Court denied petition to hear further appeal. See also the amicus brief of US executive branch officials.
So for the experimental use defense to succeed in the US, the burden is to show that the use was "solely for amusement, to satisfy idle curiosity, or for strictly philosophical inquiry".

I've just asked in Academia SE Do academic researchers generally not worry about their work infringing on patents? Have there been cases where they wish they had?

I know Universities think an awful lot about Standford vs. Roche.
